# mean stack missing folders

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

Installing a mean stack:

```
$ sudo npm install -g meanio 

$ mean init yourNewApp
```

Checking file structure:

```
$ ls

AUTHORS     Procfile    config      packages
Gruntfile.js    README.md   karma.conf.js   server.js
LICENSE     bower.json  package.json
```

I am missing the correct file structure even though the app "works". Everything should be installed correctly. Where is public and the server folder?

These folders are also missing if I clone any other mean stack project from github.

Answer (score 9):

I had a same problem because I am beginner, but it seems that MEAN Stack file structure has been changed few weeks ago. Quote from Mean.io docs says:

> 'From v0.4.0 all the application code has been integrated into a number of packages. Each package uses MVC on the server and client. Below is the overall file structure as well as the package file structure'

Source: http://mean.io/#!/docs

This mean.io file structure is organised in packages and each package has own MVC for server/client sides folders. Also, please take a look on mean.io blog site where there is article about package types: http://blog.mean.io/2014/06/extending-mean-io/

Comment: typmekpu great answer!! I am one of the mean.io core developers and we are working on more detailed and explicit documents to make thigns clearer

Comment: To Yonatan: You guys are doing a great job but the doc is too way old, since your answer on July!!

Comment: have there been changes again @YonatanEllman ? I am missing the app and public folders... making every single resource I've read so far very confusing...

Answer (score 2):

### If you are windows user and you try to follow mean.io website instructions, you probably will be confused how to install all the stuff in order to see the application lunched in your browser and probably you can't manage to have all the sources in your project. Follow their video from homepage or **DO THIS**:

1. Install Git from `http://msysgit.github.io/` and then in then fallow
   the instructions from here
   `http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm` in order to add your
   “git” var path;
2. Install node.js from `http://nodejs.org/`;
3. Install MongoDB from `http://www.mongodb.org/`. Create in your "C:\" the "data" directory and inside of "data" create "db" directory. Add like step one a new PATH var but this time for mongodb. For this you should find out your mongodb root in the window system (ex: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin`).
4. Run in cmd: npm install -g meanio ;
5. Run in cmd: mean init myApp;
6. Go into myApp folder using cmd and there run: npm install;
7. Run in new cmd window in C:\ : mongod;
8. Run in new cmd window but this time in your myApp location: grunt. If you obtain an error saying that grunt is not recognized then run this comand line "npm install -g grunt-cli";
9. Go in browser and type `http://localhost:3000/`.

---

Hope this will be useful for someone new like me in this area.

Comment: I guess the question was not about installing and running the mean stack application rather about missing folders.

Answer (score 1):

In Mean.IO total project is divided into number of modules and these modules are known as package. these packages mostly independent from each other. and each package contains public and private folder separately. for more see the mean documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing meanjs. It's a fork from the mean.io. Many developers have shifted to meanjs as it's more stable and from the same guy Amos Haviv who started mean.io.